# Can I use the c# rest library to call a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, restful-url

Can I use the C# REST library to make these web service calls instead of discovering the web service like we do below?

ex of a web service we're calling

```
https://trustonline.delawarecpf.com/tows/webservicefk.svc
```

The problem is, we have a .cs file for each web service with pretty much all the same code to call up the web service and fetch/add/edit data. The only differences are the web services each file references are different.

Ex. in each file we access a user like this

```
var user = new User();
```

where User is

```
ServiceReferenceFK.User() // from the FK service reference
```

or

```
ServiceReferenceAB.User() // from the AB service reference
```

But I'd rather use the REST library to fetch/edit/add/delete data so to eliminate all the redundant files. And move to a single file for all services.

Currently we do this in solution explorer under project

[image]

then we add a service reference like this below and hit discover.
VS finds the url and gets us all the code to use.

[image]

Comment: That isn't a restful service.  That's SOAP.

Comment: And what is "the REST library"?

Comment: http://restsharp.org/

Comment: *Can* you use Restsharp with a SOAP service?  Probably.  But I would not recommend it.

Comment: hi Amy. I'm just trying to figure out how to eliminate redundancy across all the "SOAP" web services we're calling. Each one is from the same vendor (ex. same methods, prop, classes, etc) but our project has 12 .cs files, each with the same calls, and each call in each file is to a difference web service reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an abstract base class. To make it work your abstract class needs to be `[serializable]` or `[Datacontract]` or it won't be able to expose the class to the client, e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class MyBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public abstract int DoAdd { get; set; }

    public void MyOtherFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

}
[DataContract]
public class MyWCF : MyBase
{
    int a;
    [DataMember]
    public override int DoAdd
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
}
```